# How can I call a callback that depends on an updated state in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

```js
function useRequest() {

  const [accessToken, setAccessToken] = useState(42);
  const [refreshToken, setRefreshToken] = useState(7);
  
  const request = async (url) => {
    try {
      const res = await axios.get(url, { Headers: { Auth: accessToken } });
    } catch (error) {
      if (error.response.status === 401) {
        refresh(() => request(url));
      }
    }
  }
  
  const refresh = async (callback) => {
    const res = await axios.get("myserver.com", { params: { refreshToken }});
    setAccessToken(res.data.accessToken);
    callback()
  }
  
  return request;

}
```

So I want to call this api and refresh the access token if it expires. Problem is, when I set the access token state in the refresh function, the callback is called with the old state because setState is async. In other contexts, I could just use useEffect but i'm not sure what to do in this case.

Comment: why can't you use useEffect?

Comment: What would the `useEffect` look like? It feels like I would have to add another `useState` to hold callbacks that need to be called after the access token updates. But then there's the question of how be sure the callback state was updated before the access token state is. @Cole's suggestion to use a ref will work in my case, but I'd be interested to see  how `useEffect` would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to store `accessToken` in a `ref` instead of in `state`.

Official react documentation: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref

`useState` is async because React assumes state is related to the UI, so state updates are coupled to the React render lifecycle.

Updating the `ref` is synchronous, and is a good option for persisting data that doesn't need to trigger UI updates.

Your code, but using `useRef`

```
function useRequest() {

  const accessTokenRef = useRef(42);
  const [refreshToken, setRefreshToken] = useState(7);
  
  const request = async (url) => {
    try {
      const res = await axios.get(url, { Headers: { Auth: accessTokenRef.current } });
    } catch (error) {
      if (error.response.status === 401) {
        refresh(() => request(url));
      }
    }
  }
  
  const refresh = async (callback) => {
    const res = await axios.get("myserver.com", { params: { refreshToken }});
    accessTokenRef.current = res.data.accessToken;
    callback()
  }
  
  return request;

}
```

Comment: you could probably consider storing your `accessToken` in a ref as well, since it's probably not tied to the render lifecycle either

Comment: This works great! You're right that the tokens aren't really related to the UI, they just need to persist between renders so a ref is just what I need. Thank you @Cole!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use `useEffect` for whatever reason, another option would be to pass the state you set to the `request` function, so that it doesn't depend on external variables.

```
const request = async (url, accessToken = 42) => {
    try {
        const res = await axios.get(url, { Headers: { Auth: accessToken } });
    } catch (error) {
        if (error.response.status === 401) {
            refresh((accessToken) => request(url, accessToken));
        }
    }
}

const refresh = async (callback) => {
    const res = await axios.get("myserver.com");
    const { accessToken } = res.data;
    setAccessToken(accessToken);
    callback(accessToken);
}
```